# Load Testing of Websockets with a sustained concurrent connections of 1million plus

Tags: websocket, performance-testing, load-testing

Has anybody done Performance testing of web sockets protocol for 1Million+ sustained concurrent connections and if so what tool is recommended for this purpose and will it integrate into a CICD pipeline ?

Thank you,
Prashat

Couldnt find anything out there

Answer (score 0):

There are many load testing tools which support WebSockets, for example:

- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/websocket/)
- [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org) with [WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers) plugin
- [Locust](https://locust.io/) with [WebSocket](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/socketio_ex.py) plugin
- [k6](https://k6.io/) with [xk6-websockets](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-websockets)

Given your "1Million+ sustained concurrent connections" requirement the tool needs the ability to be run in [clustered mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster) because a single machine cannot establish more than 65k connections per network interface. Theoretically all of them can, but only JMeter and Locust support distributed execution out of the box.

So the choice is up to you: whether you prefer coding in Python or building script in GUI using logical blocks.

Both tools are CI/CD friendly because they can be run in command-line unattended mode, you might want to check your continuous integration server for explicit support of the tool, i.e. there is [Performance Plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/) which supports JMeter in terms of building performance trend charts and applying pass/fail criteria (comparison of response times with pre-defined values or to previous build or to reference build)

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitri T.

I have been looking at Locust and JMeter, the CICD tool we plan on using is Harness. I will review all the links you have shared above is there any documentation or an article that will help us understand  how we achieve this scale. 

All apps are Java based. Step 1 would be to Open a connection and keep it open by doing a ping pong. Infact through Jmeter using the WS sampler I have been able to successfully make a request and get a response last night, trying to understand the methodology to scale the technical aspects of it.

Thank you,